# Handling Bootstrap active tabs in Yii2 via URL

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, yii2

I'm using [Tab-x](http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x) in yii2. my codes are these

```
$items = [

    [
        'label'=>'<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> '.Yii::t('app', 'Create Category'),
        'linkOptions'=>['data-url'=>Url::to(['/site/createcategory'])],
        'active'=>TRUE
    ],


];
// Ajax Tabs Above
echo TabsX::widget([
    'items'=>$items,
    'position'=>TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
    'encodeLabels'=>false
]);
```

I want to show my active item that handles via url when my page is loading.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind to write a script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs-krajee .nav-tabs .active a').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Please, show your `var_dump(Yii::$app->controller->id, Yii::$app->controller->action->id);`

Comment: string(4) "site" string(5) "index"

Comment: You can further explain the problem?

Comment: Yes ofcourse,thank you for your response.please view this link http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x#usage-ajax  ,Ajax Tabs part usage.there is a local data that initial in home tab.when you click at home you get Ajax Tab 1 content.I want to get Ajax Tab 1 content without any clicking when home is active

Comment: `<div id="tabs-krajee-container" class=" tabs-above tab-align-left tab-bordered tabs-krajee">
<ul id="tabs-krajee" class="nav nav-tabs nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-krajee-tabsx="tabsX_00000000">
<li class="active">
<a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-url="/site/createcategory" href="#tabs-krajee-tab0">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
new category 
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tabs-krajee-tab0" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: There are errors in the console log, after executed my js script?

Comment: no there aren't.  `$('.tabs-krajee .nav-tabs .active a')` get active li correctly but doesn't trigger click

Comment: Try to run the script `$('.tabs-krajee .nav-tabs .active a').trigger('click');` directly in the browser console